# Gimp scriptfu procedure name of Colors->Map->Rotate Colors

Tags: gimp, gimpfu

The title basically says it all.
I fail to find the script fu gimp procedure that acts like what you get in the Colors->Map->Rotate Colors menu.

Besides, is there a general way to get the procedure names from the menu items?

Comment: I've figured out how to use it with GEGL command line (on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install gegl`). Example for `Rotate Colors`: `gegl 00001.png -o output.png -- color-rotate src-from=20 src-to=60 dest-from=200 dest-to=220`. Parameters: `https://www.gegl.org/operations/gegl-color-rotate.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu items with a "G" icon are implemented with GEGL. There is no easy way to script GEGL calls from scripts, but some people managed to do it [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Scripting-GEGL-operations).

GEGL is also a standalone CLI application so if you just want to apply the procedure in batch you can likely skip the Gimp part.

AFAIK there is no general way to get GEGL functions from menu items, except looking for similar names, and then nothing mandates it is a one-to-one mapping, some GIMP menus could use the same GEGL function in different ways, while other group together some GEGL functions or use them with other Gimp operations.